# Stop Repeating Background Image in UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimageview, uitextview

How do you stop an Image from repeating in an UITextView? What I want to achieve is have a UITextView that has text loaded from a .txt file (already works) and loads a preview image (already works) and finally I want the background to display my Logo at the top along with background colors I've made (all in 1 .png file), while when you scroll, the logo will go away and the rest of the background will scroll as well. My problem is that the Image repeats near the end of the text. If I make the image larger, my Logo stretches and looks sloppy, I'd like to keep the image at (0,0,480,However high the text is) and still keep the integrity of the logo in tact. I've tried searching the other similar questions but they all seem to want the repeat and I do not. Suggestions?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the current result?

Answer (score 0):

What about having a UIImageView that acts as a background image and setting the background for the textView to transparent - will it help?

Comment: it will only scroll the text, the background image will be stationary and the logo makes the text hard to read

Comment: again can you post a screenshot of the result you currently get - it will help to see what you are doin. You can insert image by editing your post.